# Query by child and key

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I have a list of patients and different users can access them. I therefore have this structure in Firebase

[image: screenshot ot firebase structure]

All patients are in patients ref.
So basically, I'd like to retrieve the patients that match on the key which is the user's UID.
Ideally, I will filter that data on the read/write/detail part as well since the secretary for example would have writing rights to modify the contact data but no access to the detail, while an apprentice would have full detail no modifying rights.

**What I have (which doesn't work):**

```
var patientsRef = firebase.database().ref('patients').orderByChild('users').orderByKey().equalTo(uid);
```

And there's the problem: I can't find an apporpriate reference to my question in the documentation. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure chaining orderBy methods works?

Comment: No, the problem is you can only `orderby` once ! I wanted to avoid pulling all the data but it seems that I don't have a choice... !

Comment: Yeah, seems like you're gonna have to workaround this, 
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using such a nested structure is generally advised against with Firebase. It makes querying close to impossible (as you've experienced), along with applying any access control to the patient data.

Keep in mind that a query requires read access to the parent node, and if that is granted, no children data can be hidden, ever.

---

The typical solution would be moving this patient-user relationship to a separate root node. The actual patient data should only be readable one-by-one, if there is a matching relationship (ACL) node for them.

Preferably "invert" the relationship too: store the patients per user, not users per patient, so your application can directly display them as a list.

A proposal:

```
/patients
    /PATIENTID1
        ... sensitive data
    /PATIENTID2
        ... sensitive data

/users
    /USERID1
        ...
    /USERID2
        ...

/user-patients
    /USERID1
        /PATIENTID1
            "name": "Patient name" (redundant copy for easy display)
            "detail": true,
            "write": false,
            ...
```

Your application will load `/user-patients` to show a personalized list of the patients the current user can access. Security rules can also use this directly (with the `root` variable) to make sure no one reads or writes what they are not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: read the comment thread of this answer on why you should not do it this way. Please see vzsgs answer.

---

I would suggest adding a different part to your json so that it can be queried. One of the main points in firebase is to structure the data to be easily query-able and so sometimes you have to duplicate data. (P.s. next time paste your json)

```
{
    "c237CV45SbhHfaRoicVyvFuy8e88" : {
        "firstName" : "Emeline",
        "gender": "f",
        "lastname": "Zagaroli",
        "users": {
            "p0R3CV45SBgGfaRoicVyvFuy8tq1": {
                "detail": true,
                "read": true,
                "write": true
            }
        },
        "usersAssoc": {
            "p0R3CV45SBgGfaRoicVyvFuy8tq1": true
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can write a query like so:

```
var patientsRef = firebase.database().ref('patients').orderByChild('usersAssoc/p0R3CV45SBgGfaRoicVyvFuy8tq1').equalTo(true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's a serious performance and security issue with this approach. 1) unless every single user is added to the `patients` node's `.indexOn` security rule - which is not really feasible -, this query would download everything and perform the filtering on the client side. 2) it requires `/patients` to be readable by everyone.

Comment: This would not download everything, the query is performed on the server and only the true values are returned. orderBy is not executed client side.

Comment: If and only if the index is set. That's a prerequisite for the server-side filtering to work.

Comment: You're correct, I wasn't able to find it in the docs but did find it when I created a test. Tossed an upvote to your answer and TIL.

Comment: OK thank you for all your answers. Your answer is correct and the appropriate approach regarding my question but vzsg has included the security issue which I did not take into account (I used firebase for the first time in any project so still learning). Do you mind if I select his answer since it would be way better for other users who find this question ?

Comment: I've already edited mine to say that his is better. Yes please accept his.